# Handling Observable in CanDeactivate

Tags: angular

I have an interceptor which catches server errors when the token is expired. Then the interceptor asks the api for a refreshed token. On success the interceptor sends the http request again. On error the interceptor deletes the local storage and should redirect to login page.

Now I have a page with a canDeactivate Guard. So I want to check in canDeactivate Guard if token is valid. If it is not valid I want to ask the API for a refreshed token. On success I don't want to leave the page. On error I want to logout the user and redirect to login page.

```
// canDeactivateGuard
export interface CanComponentDeactivate {
  canDeactivate: () => Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CanDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<CanComponentDeactivate> {
  canDeactivate(component: CanComponentDeactivate) {
    return component.canDeactivate ? component.canDeactivate() : true;
  }
}
```

```
// component
canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    if (!this.authService.isTokenValid()) {
      // here i want to ask the api for a new token
      // on error of api I want to redirect the user to login page
      // and don't want to show a modal
      return this.authService.refreshToken().pipe(
        map(res => {
          console.log('test');
          return false;
        }),
        catchError(err => {
          console.log('test error');
          return of(true);
        })
      );
    }
    if (Object.is(this.testForm.get('text').value, this.oldText)) {
      this.modalService.hide(1);
      return true;
    } else {
      this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(this.modalTemplate);
      return false;
    }
  }
```

```
// AuthService
 public refreshToken(): Observable<Token> {
    return this.http.post<{ data: any }>(`${environment.apiUrl}/auth/refresh`, {}).pipe(
      map(({ data }): any => {
        const apiToken = this.tokenAdapter.adapt(data);
        this.setJwtToken(apiToken);
        this.currentTokenSubject.next(apiToken);
        return apiToken;
      })
    );
  }
```

I don't know how to change the code that the error is catched from api and how I can redirect the user. Both console.logs in map() and in catchError() of canDeactivate Method are not called.

Comment: Try `return this.authService.refreshToken()` from `canDeactivate` method. You don't return the Observable so no one subscribes to it and that's why `map` and `catchError` are not called

Comment: Oh yes sorry, I forgot it. I have already tryed it to return the observable but it doesn't work. The difference is that the modal is not opened and when I don't return the Observable the modal is opened.
I have added the return in my post.

Comment: Then why don't you move modal logic into the observable?

Comment: The console logs in the observable are not called, so the modal won't open too.

Answer (score 0):

the refreshToken should follow the below format, this would be helpful

```
    return this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/auth/refresh`, {
    }).pipe(
      map(({ data }): any => {
        const apiToken = this.tokenAdapter.adapt(data);
        this.setJwtToken(apiToken);
        this.currentTokenSubject.next(apiToken);
        return apiToken;
      }),
      catchError(() => {
      return of(false);
    }));
```

Then in the canDeactivate method

```
// component
canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
  if(!this.authService.isTokenValid()) {
  // here i want to ask the api for a new token
  // on error of api I want to redirect the user to login page
  // and don't want to show a modal
  return this.authService.refreshToken().pipe(
    map(res => {
      if (!res) {
        console.log('test error');
        return true;
      }

      console.log('test');
      return false;
    })
  );
}
if (Object.is(this.testForm.get('text').value, this.oldText)) {
  this.modalService.hide(1);
  return true;
} else {
  this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(this.modalTemplate);
  return false;
}
    }
```

Comment: I have tried this but the console logs are not called in canDeactivate Method

Comment: I have tried to put a console log in  the catchError of refreshToken, but it is not called too.

Comment: does it go to map, with http 500 ? that very strange

Comment: You mean if it calls this console log in this code snippet?

```
map(res => {
      if (!res) {
        console.log('test error');
        return true;
      }
```

No this console log is not called.

Comment: the map in refreshToken, I mean to ask

Comment: I have added a console log after `this.setJwtToken(apiToken);` and it is not called

Comment: then there might be a bug in this.setJwtToken(apiToken)

Comment: this is the setJwtToken Method: private setJwtToken(token: Token): void {
    localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(token));
    this.currentTokenSubject.next(token);
  }